# Using filter instead of subset in Shiny datatables R

Tags: r, dplyr, shiny

I have a Shiny dashboard where I have a datatable and I want to pass along and filter from an input field.  I tried to reproduce the code below.  You can see that in the UI the first row has a numericInput that produces a number that I want to pass along to the 2 datatables below.  In the first instance, I tried applying a dplyr filter at the end to no success.  The second datatable works with a subset, however I feel this feels inefficient and I cant (as far as I can tell) apply the table features onto a subset table (as in, I cannot apply things like formatCurrency to the subset table).  I am only trying to apply the table formatting in the first table to the second table, so if that is workable with subset I am good w/ that.  It just seems like applying a filter might be easier.  Thank you in advance...

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)
library(plotly)

shinyUI(
  dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = "Sales Performance Dashboard", titleWidth = 250,
                    dropdownMenu(type = "message",
                                 messageItem(from = "Finance Update", message = "Updated 6/30/2020")
                    )
    ),
    tabItem(tabName = "main",
            fluidRow(
              box(title = "Customer Search", status = "primary", solidHeader = T, width = 4,  numericInput("num", "Enter Customer ID", value = 1001002, min = 10000, max = 150000))
            ),
            fluidRow(
              box(title = "Sales Averages", status = "primary", solidHeader = T, width = 12, DT::dataTableOutput("Master"))
            ),
            fluidRow(
              box(title = "Min/Max/Med", status = "primary", solidHeader = T, width = 12, DT::dataTableOutput("Master1"))


shinyServer(function(input,output){
  
output$Master <-DT::renderDataTable(
    DT::datatable(Master, selection = 'single', filter = 'top', rownames = F,
                  options = list(pageLength = 10, autoWidth = TRUE, columnDefs = list(list(className = 'dt-center', targets = 2:14),list(width = '115px', targets = c(1:3))))) %>% formatCurrency(c(6:8,13:15), '')) **%>% filter(`Customer ID` == input$num)**
  
output$Master1 <- renderDataTable(
Master1 <- subset(Master, Master$CustomerID == input$num, selection = 'single', rownames = F))

})


shinyApp(shinyUI, shinyServer)
```

Answer (score 0):

You really should post a small dataframe to easily debug your code.  I have used `gapminder` data from gapminder package.  You were missing some syntax and you need to use `!!` when using `input$num`. The code below works on `gapminder` data. You should be able to use it on your data and make appropriate modifications as necessary.

```
library(gapminder)
data(gapminder, package = "gapminder")
Master <- gapminder %>% mutate(CustomerID=year)
ui <- dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = "Sales Performance Dashboard", titleWidth = 250,
                    dropdownMenu(type = "message",
                                 messageItem(from = "Finance Update", message = "Updated 6/30/2020")
                    )
    ),
    dashboardSidebar(width = 250,
                     sidebarMenu(
                       # Setting id makes input$tabs give the tabName of currently-selected tab
                       id = "tabs", 
                       menuItem("Home", tabName = "home", icon = icon("home")),
                       menuItem("Customer Search", icon = icon("bar-chart-o"),
                                numericInput("num", "Enter Customer ID", value = 1952, min = 1952, max = 2007))
                                
                       )
    ),
    dashboardBody(
    tabItem(tabName = "main",
            # fluidRow(
            #   box(title = "Customer Search", status = "primary", solidHeader = T, width = 4,  numericInput("num", "Enter Customer ID", value = 1952, min = 1952, max = 2007))
            # ),
            fluidRow(
              box(title = "Sales Averages", status = "primary", solidHeader = T, width = 12, DT::dataTableOutput("Master"))
            ),
            fluidRow(
              box(title = "Min/Max/Med", status = "primary", solidHeader = T, width = 12, DT::dataTableOutput("Master1"))
            ))
    ))

server <- function(input,output,session){
  
  output$Master <-DT::renderDataTable(
    DT::datatable(Master, selection = 'single', filter = 'top', rownames = F,
                  options = list(pageLength = 5, autoWidth = TRUE #, 
                                 #columnDefs = list(list(className = 'dt-center', targets = 2:14),list(width = '115px', targets = c(1:3)))
                                 )) # %>% 
      # formatCurrency(c(6:8,13:15), '')
    )  ## %>% filter(`Customer ID` == input$num) 
  
  output$Master1 <- renderDataTable(
    Master1 <- Master %>%  subset(CustomerID == input$num))
  
}        
              
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

It gives the following output:

[image: output1]

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply!  I will take your advice.  In the example above, how would I go about passing along the numericInput into the first table, output$Master using dplyr filter?  %>% filter(`Customer ID` == input$num)  does not seem to work for me.  Any suggestions would be helpful...thank you!

Comment: I think it might be best to define CustomerID, without a space in the column name.  Without a small data sample, I cannot show how to fix your data structure issue.  This program works fine for me.